# How did I remove NaN characters from the introduction?

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

While I was revising the introduction to Java's topic on regular expressions, I got this gem:

[image: A topic outline saying "NaN characters removed" for the introduction]

Which is obviously a bug. Who's around to fix this?

Since I'm guessing the client side code did this, I will provide my user-agent string below.

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 10_2_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.4.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14D27 Safari/602.1

Comment: But NaN words _were_ removed. Words are usually not numbers

Comment: How did you do it? http://imgur.com/iZcUNxH, obviously.

Comment: I have a partial fix for this ready to go to production with the next build. When the introduction section has a value before and after the edit, there will be a word count shown rather than a NaN. Edits either from an empty section or erasing the entire introduction blurb are still not counted correctly. That's on the list for tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use [jsdiff](https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff) for tracking changes. Turns out, we were a few versions behind (on 2.0.1 vs the current 3.2.0). I pushed the upgrade, and it should fix the NaN issue.

The word counts are still a bit off (e.g it'll say 3 words removed instead of 2... possibly counting the space?), but that seems to be just how jsdiff counts things and not something we're doing ourselves. I'm gonna call this status-completed for the moment. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

The upgrade is going live with the next production build (> rev. 2017.2.16.25130).